# More capable alternative to XMLHttpRequest available for Firefox add-ons?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

I am currently writing an add-on for Firefox that uses `XMLHttpRequest` to send some HTTP requests to a remote server. However, I have run into the following limitations:

- `XMLHttpRequest` transparently follows HTTP 3xx redirects (which is undesired)
- `XMLHttpReques`t ignores `setRequestHeader` for certain headers (such as `User-Agent`)
- HTTP Basic Authentication is also handled by the browser - prompting the user for credentials with no way to disable this behavior

For these reasons (and possibly others), I am looking for an alternative means to send HTTP requests from within a Firefox add-on. I've looked around MDN quite a bit but haven't come across anything that seems to meet my needs.

Does such a class exist?

**Note:** I am not using the SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd keep using `XHR`, but set own notification callbacks and manipulating the headers directly on the channel.

Each `XHR` has a channel, which is (usually) a [`nsIHttpChannel`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/protocol/http/nsIHttpChannel.idl) which is also a [`nsIHttpChannelInternal`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/protocol/http/nsIHttpChannelInternal.idl) (among other things).

E.g. the following should cover your second point.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (req.channel instanceof Ci.nsIHttpChannel) {
  req.channel.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "helloworldbot/1.0", false);
}
```

I [implemented notifications callbacks](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/blob/master/extension/modules/api/GM_xmlhttpRequester.js#L12) a while back in Scriptish to allow users to ignore redirects, which is more or less your first point.

The auth stuff is a bit nasty. You can use `XHR.open()` with the optional user/password parameters, or construct the auth header yourself and/or implement `nsIAuthPrompt`/`nsIPrompt` via notification callbacks.

If there are other problems with `XHR`, you could still go to plain, low-level `channels` (`nsIIOService.newChannel...()`), although all the goodies that XHR provides aren't there anymore.

As your question is too unspecific, I won't go into more details at this point.